# Kafka reassign partition - how to keep moved segment files modification date?

Tags: apache-kafka, filesystems

After moving all data from one disk to another on every Kafka broker using kafka-reassign-partitions cli
I went through some weird behaviour.

Basically the disk storage kept increasing even though there is no change on `bytes in` metric per broker.

After investigation, I’ve seen that all segment log files in the new log.dir had a modification time set to the moment when the move had been done.

So I guess the process applying the retention policy (log cleaner?) uses that timestamp to check whether the segment file should be deleted or not.

So I ended with a lot more data than we supposed to store, since we are basically doubling the retention time of all the freshly moved data.

It seems a bit odd that the command doesn’t handle that somehow when moving the data.

How do we move partitions in kafka and ensure their retention policy is still respected?
Thanks

Comment: Did you *experiment* changing the modification time using *touch* command? Eg. `touch -a -m -t 203801181205.09 your_file`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I would like to avoid touching the segment files manually to be honest. That would be the last option I would consider.